# How to filter table for multi column combination

Tags: excel, filtering

I have a table with two columns. First column is an operator (+ or -), second column is a reference, for excel its a simple text.
I want to remove all rows from my table (e.g. with a filter) where for a + there is at least one corresponding - entry in the reference column.

I checked the filter section but this only works for single columns not a combined mode.

example:

```
operator | Reference
+ | Task1
- | Task1
+ | Task2
- | Task3
+ | Task4
- | Task4
```

Expected result:

```
operator | Reference
+ | Task2
- | Task3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an easier formula but that doesn't come to mind, but if you interested in doing this through formula's you could try this:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(D2,$B$2:$B$7,0)),"")
```

Formula in `D2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,$B$2:$B$7)=1,ROW($A$2:$A$7),0),SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,$B$2:$B$7))+ROW()-1)),"")
```

Last formula is an array formula entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down....